# mysql query with explode

Tags: mysql, explode, separator

I have a table with this type of value 20|10|5|8|19| (with separator)

I need to select rows, where first value (for example after explode), less than 20.

```
$arr = explode("|", "goal_times");
$first_goal_time = $arr[0];
```

But how to do this in Mysql query?

Comment: I need to have number of rows with this condition.

Answer (score 1):

In general you shouldn't have multiple values with separator in the same column. In this case you can get away with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`

```
SELECT * 
 FROM yourtable 
 WHERE 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,'|',1) < 20;
```

Comment: Add a silent conversion of string to integer as `SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,'|',1)+0`

Comment: Is it not good idea to have multiple values in the same column? I need to save goals minutes, authors, tima for each game.